# Is there a way to groupby columns that are similar?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a table like this:

| University | Course |
| --- | --- |
| Stanford | Financial Accounting |
| Stanford | Managerial Accounting |
| Yale | Managerial Accounting |
| Harvard | Corporate Finance |
| University of Oregon | Accounting & Finance |

I would like to group them where part of the string matches and it only counts once per University like this:

| Course | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Accounting | 3 |
| Finance | 2 |
| Managerial | 2 |
| Financial | 1 |
| Corporate | 1 |

Currently I have this group by statement that shows top string matches:

```
groups = dataFrame.groupby('Course')['University'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

And it returns:

| Course | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Financial Accounting | 1 |
| Managerial Accounting | 2 |
| Corporate Finance | 1 |

Does anyone know a way to group the similar courses based on similar matches rather than exact matches?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What does "similar" mean here? If the first entry was "Finance & Accounting" what would be the expected output?

Comment: @Mr.T ideally it should count 1 for Finance and 1 for Accounting for that school. Let me improve the example to show that

Comment: So, why is there no count for `M̀anagerial`, `Financial`, and `Corporate`? I find it difficult to understand your rules.

Comment: @Mr.T there should be, this was just a small example though. But you are correct, let me update it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `Series.str.get_dummies` and manually pick out the columns:

```
counts = df['Course'].drop_duplicates().str.get_dummies(' ').sum()[['Accounting', 'Finance']].to_frame().reset_index().set_axis(['Course', 'Count'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> counts
       Course  Count
0  Accounting      2
1     Finance      1
```

Or maybe it's simpler and you just want to select the last part of each value:

```
counts = df['Course'].drop_duplicates().str.split(' ').str[-1].value_counts().reset_index().set_axis(['Course', 'Count'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> counts
       Course  Count
0  Accounting      2
1     Finance      1
```

Comment: this is a great solution, thank you very much, I can work with this. I may need to adjust a few things but this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Just realized this doesn't pick out courses uniquely per university though. I tried running both versions and they return more 'Management' courses than there are schools. I'm trying to add 1 if the university has a course with a certain wording

Comment: I can probably fix that for you @Yash, but you'll need to provide a bit more sample data so that I can reproduce the problem myself.